# Braintree invalid keys with transaction creation

Tags: php, braintree

I thought I was following the Braintree PHP SDK setup step-by-step from the official documentation but I must have missed something. I keep getting this fatal error when trying to create a transaction through the use of a nonce that is generated and supplied to the server by the client. I must be missing something obvious! Thank you.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: invalid keys: paymentMethodNonce[binData][commercial], paymentMethodNonce[binData][countryOfIssuance], paymentMethodNonce[binData][debit], paymentMethodNonce[binData][durbinRegulated], paymentMethodNonce[binData][healthcare], paymentMethodNonce[binData][issuingBank], paymentMethodNonce[binData][payroll], paymentMethodNonce[binData][prepaid], paymentMethodNonce[binData][productId], paymentMethodNonce[description], paymentMethodNonce[details][cardType], paymentMethodNonce[details][lastFour], paymentMethodNonce[details][lastTwo], paymentMethodNonce[nonce], paymentMethodNonce[type] in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\btree\lib\Braintree\Util.php:349

Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\btree\lib\Braintree\TransactionGateway.php(47): Braintree\Util::verifyKeys(Array, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\btree\lib\Braintree\TransactionGateway.php(304): Braintree\TransactionGateway->create(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\theme in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\btree\lib\Braintree\Util.php on line 349
```

**init.php**

```
<?php
require 'lib/Braintree.php';

session_start();

$gateway = new Braintree_Gateway([
    'environment' => 'sandbox',
    'merchantId' => 'cys2',
    'publicKey' => 'h9v7',
    'privateKey' => '7fbca5'
]);
```

**read_nonce.php**

```
<?php
require '../init.php';

$clientNonce = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"];

print_r($clientNonce);

$result = $gateway->transaction()->sale([
    'amount' => '10.00',
    'paymentMethodNonce' => $clientNonce,
    'options' => [
        'submitForSettlement' => True
    ]
]);
```

*$clientNonce*

```
Array
(
    [nonce] => tokencc_bd_8pccr_vq5wfj_h2pxbf_kn99n4_6c7
    [details] => Array
        (
            [cardType] => Discover
            [lastFour] => 1117
            [lastTwo] => 17
        )

    [type] => CreditCard
    [description] => ending in 17
    [binData] => Array
        (
            [prepaid] => Unknown
            [healthcare] => Unknown
            [debit] => Unknown
            [durbinRegulated] => Unknown
            [commercial] => Unknown
            [payroll] => Unknown
            [issuingBank] => Unknown
            [countryOfIssuance] => Unknown
            [productId] => Unknown
        )

)
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'btree/init.php';

$clientToken = $gateway->clientToken()->generate();

?>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.10.0/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dropin-container"></div>
  <button id="submit-button">Request payment method</button>
  <script>
    var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

    braintree.dropin.create({
      authorization: '<?=$clientToken?>',
      container: '#dropin-container'
    }, function (createErr, instance) {
      button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
          console.log(payload);
          $.ajax({
            url : 'btree/ajax/read_nonce.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
              payment_method_nonce : payload
            }
          }).done(function(r){

          });
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologizes, I misread.

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php#payment_method_token

`paymentMethodNonce` is passed as a string.

Appropriate change was simply:

```
'paymentMethodNonce' => $clientNonce
```

to

```
'paymentMethodNonce' => $clientNonce['nonce']
```